# Alternate model for form

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 2.1 preview, I have a view model with several properties which provide unrelated data. From within this view, I want to create a form and post back to the controller using the provided validation and display name tag helpers.

How can I reference an alternate model in the form configuration, the `asp-for` helpers work against the current model which has nothing to do with the form in question.

Comment: You need to create a view model with properties needed for the view and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the View Model with your required attributes and validations and use them in your view. You can even combine multiple models in one view models and use them as required.

```
public class MovieVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
  [Required]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

  [Range(1, 100)]
  [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
  public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

In your view you can use them like In you view you can use them like `@model MovieVM` and acess their property in your form.

Comment: Brilliant, so I am supplying the supplementary data through an array property on the view model and now I need to send it back during the form post with a hidden input so it can be returned on error. The object type in the array is a POCO with a string and int property, how can I get that returned properly?

Comment: Have you tried playing with sample projects generated through VS? You can go through official doc [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1]

Comment: Yup, and I am using client side validation which makes the requirement mostly unnecessary however without the collection persisted during a round trip, it requires db access to refresh. Not the end of the world, I can encode the collection and handle replacing it if I really need to.